# Stream- or datagram sockets for messanger app

Tags: java, android, sockets, chat

I am trying to make a small messanger app on android with java that can send text to other people.
Like the facebook messanger or Whatsapp.
I don't want to make the new Facebook Messanger or Whatsapp its just for fun.

So I have a question, which one, the Streamsockets or the Datagramsockets are used to transfer such things or are there other better ways?
And are these classes suitable if 200.000 people(It's just for me but I want to make it the right way) would use this app?

The basic communication model I thought would be, there is a main Server that has access to a database that contains all the usere profiles with their messages and informations.
Now if someone write a message the app connects to the server and give him the message app and finally disconnect, the server store the informations than simply in the database.
So at last the app would connect to the server in regularly intervals, to ask for new messages, get them if yes, and disconnect again.

Thanks for reading.
Maybe someone can help me to get on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use a stream (e.g. tcp). To ensure that your messages were received by your server easy. If you use datagram (e.g. udp) you must ensure no data was lost yourself.

for 200.000 (active) people you will need a good setup either way. your OS for example has a limit for open connections. Think about scalability. E.g. message queues. You will face bigger problems than stream vs datagram which might force you to use one of them anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks. But one question: Should the connection to the server opend in the moment the user open the app and disconnect if the app closes, or connect and disconnect if a message is written and send? I mean the first approach would maybe consume more internet and the second would be more strenuous to the server.

Comment: You should try to have an event based system. you could use Google cloud messaging for example. In that case you would only open a connection if the user sends a message and close it as soon as it's done. Keep in mind that Google cloud messaging can take some time and does not guarantee the order of messages. If that is not enough you might need to keep a connection open to receive messages. this is a very complex topic and I am not an expert. I'm afraid I can not help you make this decision. Take a look at websockets too.